# Running queries on linked excel sheets in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have ~300 Excel spreadsheets linked to an Access database. Each of these spreadsheets are projecting one line of data (composed of multiple cells) to Access, and I am trying to find a way to run a query which would put all of these pieces of data onto one report.

I am relatively new to Access, but anything will help. Something creating a primary key in VBA maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to "put them together"? Are all the columns the same across the different sheets, and do you just want to append them to eachother?

Comment: Correct. The format of all of the Excel sheets are the exact same, I have them as linked tables in Access, but each workbook occupies its own table in Access, and I am trying to consolidate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a union query would do the trick.  It's a bit cumbersome to write for 300 tables, but that's basically what you need.

```
SELECT *
FROM LinkedExcelTable1

UNION (ALL) 'All if you want duplicate rows included

SELECT *
FROM LinkedExcelTable2

UNION 

SELECT *
FROM .......
```

If you need a primary key created, I'd create a new table with an AutoNumber ID and then you can just merge the above query into an append query.  Just remember if you do that you'll have to explicitly name the fields your selecting, instead of just selecting everything.